# Distinguish form action

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to delete the record from my database with a checkbox and without a checkbox, I think the form is wrong but I don't know what I must do to distinguish between the forms.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('admin/seleksi/delete')}}" >
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"> 

    <table  border="0" class="table table-striped" id="print">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="10">No</td>
                <td width="100">Nama</td>
                <td width="10"></td>
                <td width="10"></td>    
                <td width="10"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach($pelamar as $p)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
            <td>{{ $p->Nama }}</td>   
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-xs btn-primary" title="View CV" href="{{URL::to('admin/seleksi/cv/'. $p->id)}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('admin/lowongan/seleksi/delete/' . $p->pelamarid ) }}" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button title="Delete Pelamar" type="submit" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Hapus Pengumuman"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></i></button>
                </form>
                </td>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" class="checkboxes" value="{{ $p->pelamarid }}" />
            </td>
                </tr>

                @endforeach

            </table></div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!--header start-->
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete Checked</button>
                    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style=""><!--header start-->
                        <br>
                        <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/pengumuman/create/'. $cruds->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>&nbsp;Umumkan Hasil Lowongan Ini</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/lowongan/' . $cruds->id . '/view') }}"  class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>&nbsp;Download List Seleksi</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
       </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot have a form in a form, you need to separate those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest the forms, that is an invalid html markup instead of having two forms, just do one form and have two submit buttons. then each button will have an action where you want the form to be submitted, using the `button formaction Attribute`

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" formaction="{{ URL::to('admin/seleksi/delete')}}">Delete Checked</button>}

<button title="Delete Pelamar" type="submit" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Hapus Pengumuman" formmethod="{{ URL::to('admin/lowongan/seleksi/delete/' . $p->pelamarid ) }}"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></i></button>
```

Then extract only what you need in each action page.

> The formaction attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a
>   form is submitted. This attribute overrides the form's action
>   attribute.
>
> The formaction attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit".

Comment: sorry i cant upvote now, because my account recently joined stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested `<form>` which is completely wrong, Try below line instead inner form:

```
<button title="Delete Pelamar" type="submit" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Hapus Pengumuman"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></i></button>
```

**UPDATE**

you can try [HTML  formaction Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp), to submit form with different action

Comment: yes i know its wrong but i need different action for each form

Comment: @RizalImanMuttaqin check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412037/distinguish-form-action/45412285#45412285) I believe thats exactly what u need